# Markdown in Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, haml, markdown

I have written my plain page content in markdown files such as content_home.md and content_other_page.md

I am using haml for my templates and when I use the :markdown filter and paste my markdown in, it works perfectly. I then thought it would be nice to keep the actual markdown out of the view to separate the content so I remove the markdown filter and content and need a way to get it to render the real .md file at a specific point.

My questions then are as follows:

- Where is the best place to put the .md files in my Rails app structure?
- How do I call them to be rendered from within the view and for them to be processed by markdown? I would prefer it if they could be processed by the Haml markdown filter but am open to suggestions.

Neil

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using:

```
  :markdown
    #{render 'home.md'}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Embedded Markdown](https://github.com/ytbryan/emd) github page, to support Markdown rendering on Rails products

Add these lines to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'coderay' #optional for Syntax Highlighting
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'emd'
```

And then execute:

```
bundle
```

To create markdown partial, view or enable syntax highlighting on code block, visit the [usage of emd](https://github.com/ytbryan/emd#usage)